# Aggregate queries in Laravel Query Builder with group by

Tags: laravel

I have a table birds.

I want to count each kind of birds in a single query.

I want to combine these queries into a single query in Eloquent if possible.

```
 select count(id) as count1 from birds where kind = a;

 select count(id) as count2 from birds where kind = b;

 select count(id) as count2 from birds where kind = c;
```

I tried something like

```
$first = DB::table('birds')->selectRaw('count(id) as count1')->where('kind','a');
DB::table('birds')->selectRaw('count(id) as count2')->where('kind','b')->unionAll($first)->get();
```

i don't think union is giving me what i want.

i just need something like

```
DB::raw(' (select count(id) from birds where kind = a) as count1 ', ' (select count(id)  from  birds where kind = a) as count2  ', ' (select count(id) from birds where kind = a) as count3 ')
```

i want to combine the queries

like

```
Select ( select count(id)  from birds where kind = 'a') as count1, ( select count(id)  from birds where kind = 'b') as count2,  ( select count(id)  from birds where kind ='c') as count3 from birds ;
```

. please give me a tip how to achieve it.

Comment: I've rolled back your question to the one that you have accepted an answer to. This will make it more useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Learn SQL, `group by` and `aggregates` in particular.

This is what you need in Laravel:

```
DB::table('birds')
  ->selectRaw('count(id) as count, kind')
  ->groupBy('kind')
  ->lists('count', 'kind');
  // or get()
```

`lists` will return an array like below:

```
array(
  'kind_1' => '15',
  'kind_2' => '10',
  ...
);
```

`get` would return an array of `stdObjects` so probably not what you would like:

```
array(
  0 => StdObject {
    'kind' => 'kind_1',
    'count' => '15'
  },
  1 => StdObject {
    'kind' => 'kind_2',
    'count' => '10'
  },
  ...
);
```

If you want to get only particular `kinds` of birds, then use `whereIn`:

```
DB::table('birds')
  ->selectRaw('count(id) as count, kind')
  ->groupBy('kind')
  ->whereIn('kind', ['kind_1', 'kind_2', 'kind_3'])
  ->lists('count', 'kind');
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I should have used another example didn't see that coming. How do you do it if instead of kind i will query date_added.

like select count(id) as count1 from birds where date added = today/yesterday/3monthsago;

Comment: you want groupped results or just when `where` condition is matched? In fact it doesn't matter, because you still want `group by`, definitely no `union` or whatever you tried. Unless there are separate tables or anything alike.

Comment: where condition is matched. like how to combine these three:

select count(id) as count1 from birds where date_added = today;

     select count(id) as count2 from birds where date_added = 2012-10-11;

     select count(id) as count2 from birds where kind = 2012-10-9;

Comment: I mean. I need a count for each based on the date i added.

Comment: what i'm trying to achive is combine like 30 small queries to one.
select count(x) from table1 where date added = monday,
select count(x) from table1 where date added = tuesday,
select count(x) from table1 where date added = wednesday,

Comment: Like I already said. This is not the way you're doing it. You don't call 30 small queries, but one with 30 conditions. Use `where date_added in (... your values here...)` which is what I showed you.